# Очистка содержимого дива по onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Как по onclick очистить (удалить) содержимое дива?

```
function pop(image, name, price) {
    document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML = '<div id="fwind"><div id="contentwind" class="shodow15box"><div class="contentwind_head grad"></div><div class="topofimg"><img id="img" src="' + image + '" class="r5" alt="' + name + '" onload="thumb(this, 150, 150)" /></div><div class="contentwindright"><h3 class="price">Товар добавлен в корзину</h3><div class="content_text fs110"><span class="productName">' + name + '<br></span><span class="bold blue fs130">' + price + '</span></div><div class="bottom_button_add"><div id="clear_div" class="contentwind_close" onclick="clear();" title="Закрыть" ><img src="images/buttom_back_to_shopping.png" alt="Вернуться к покупкам" /></div><a rel="nofollow" href="shopping_cart.php"><img src="images/button_bg_frame.png" alt="перейти в корзину" /></a></div></div></div></div>';
    document.getElementById('fwind').style.display = 'block';
}

function clear() {
    document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML = '';
}
```

Не работает функция `clear()`.

Comment: @KoVaLsKy оба примера полностью рабочие. Мой на нативном, господина kal1sha на jQuery.

Comment: не работают.
может быть из за того что кнопка сама находится внутри дива, очистить который нужно?

Comment: походу функция clear() зарезервирована О_О ничо не понял.

Comment: А в каком браузере? Может у объекта `window` есть метод `clear()`?

Comment: @Rules а куда по вашему тогда функция попадает при вот таком способе объявления, в колодец чтоли? Всё верно, window.clear() работает исправно, когда clear() в контексте непонятно что обозначает, и поиск что-то молчит, как партизан. и toString не прокатывает. Интересно, кто объяснит это явление, интересно же!

Comment: я хромил )))
в других браузерах не пробовал. странно

Comment: Что в консоли при клике?

Answer (score 7):

```
$("div").click(function() {
$(this).html('');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
document.getElementById('elem').onclick = function() {
   this.innerHTML = '';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function clear() {
    document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML = '';
}
```

функция clear() зарезервирована, поменял на cldiv

Comment: отметьте Ваш ответ решением(галка под цифрой, слева от ответа), не оставляйте Ваш вопрос открытым.